# Making menu responsive - mobile/tablet size

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, responsive-design

So I'm working on a menu. So far I've built it and it's all looking pretty, but when it's viewed on a mobile or small tablet I want the menu to disappear to be replaced by a "MENU" button.

Any suggestions?

My menu is made from a div for each menu item rather than a list so can't find anything helpful online. cheers :)

View the menu [here](http://ahdecor8.co.uk/menu/), and the CSS [here](http://ahdecor8.co.uk/menu/stylesheet.css) .

Comment: see this tutorial explains well 
http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries
the error is only in the media css

Comment: or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: I really don't understand that well yet, I'm still in the early learning stages. Could you explain more specifically what I have to do? Sorry bit of a noob lol

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@media` queries to specify the width or height of a screen. You may be able to use this to hide the divs and show a menu icon when the screen width is smaller than a specified size.

Documentation of this can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Note: This is only fully supported in IE9 and above

Comment: I really don't understand that well yet, I'm still in the early learning stages. Could you explain more specifically what I have to do? Sorry bit of a noob lol

Comment: Are you happy to use a small bit of very simple JS?

Comment: In your CSS you have used `@media` queries, so I assume you know how to use them? Basically, when the width of the screen is smaller than a tablet screen, set CSS to `display: none` on the menu. Then create an image (of a menu button) and set it to `display: none`. When the width of the screen is small enough, set CSS `display:` `block` or `inline-block`.

Comment: Then you can use JavaScript to detect when the menu button is clicked, and change the `menu`'s CSS to `display:` `block` or `inline-block`

Comment: @ALan, if this answered your question, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

for example try put in your code to see the differences and your comment your code

```
@media (min-width:320px) { background: blue; }
@media (min-width:481px) { background: orange; }
@media (min-width:641px) { background: pink; }
@media (min-width:961px) { background: gray; }
@media (min-width:1025px) { background: white; }
@media (min-width:1281px) { background: red; }
```

Comment: I've already managed to get the menu to rescale, now I want the menu to disappear altogether on smaller screens until "MENU" is pressed. I don't know how to make the "MENU" button appear automatically on a smaller screen either.

Comment: put the code in jsfidle please